# Is there any way to export the current rendered angular page to static HTML along with all the JS functionalities?

Tags: javascript, angular8

I want to export the **rendered HTML files with its resources** to a zip file in order to share it via mail but i could not find any solution for this *usecase*. Could you please guide me how to proceed?

The web application is developed using Angular8.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I guess you had a code test or something: just build your project for development, compress the `/dist` folder and send it as a compressed file of your choice. Type and execute:

```
ng build
```

In the project main folder. Notice that `--watch` doesn’t help here, since you don’t need a CI/CD. Check [the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the Information **Federico**. My use case is to provide a export button in my page and when the use clicks it a zip file will be downloaded with the all the resources and the data which i got it from the REST